# Validating field input based on a percentage of field value

Tags: javascript

I've created a form in Acrobat XI pro.  I have 3 radio buttons, which when selected, populate a single number value into a field...here is the code I'm using for this:

```
var v = this.getField("marketRadioButtons").value;
event.value = (v=="Off") ? "" : v;
```

This works fine, but now I'm trying to restrict the user edit of this this field to a maximum 40% of the default value per selection of each radio button.

I've been able to accomplish this by simply creating 3 fields - one for each radio button, and using validation against an actual number (ie., selecting radio button1 populates text field1 with $700, so:

```
event.rc = event.value < 980 if (!event.rc) app.alert ("..."))
```

but prefer to use only one text field for each radio button value.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution! I added some new happiness that does as you wish!

The way this program works:

1. You click a checkbox.
2. You type a new value for that number.
3. You click update.
4. It updates the number by the checkboxes.

Checks:

- If the number entered is more than 1.4 * current value, an alert will fire and the value will not be updated.
- If no number is entered, nothing happens.

**Html:**

```
<form id="form1" action="">
    <input class='1' type="radio" onclick="display(this)" name="box" value="700"><span class="1">700</span><br>
    <input class='2' type="radio" onclick="display(this)" name="box" value="1200"><span class="2">1200</span><br>
    <input class='3' type="radio" onclick="display(this)" name="box" value="1500"><span class="3">1500</span>
</form><br>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="output" value="$"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="update(this)">Update</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var checkedValue = {
    'class':0,
    'value':0,
}

display = function(me) {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('output');
    textbox.value = "$" + me.value;
    checkedValue.value = Number(me.value);
    checkedValue.class = me.className;
}

update = function(me) {
    var price = me.form.output.value;
    // if no value entered, newAmount sets to 0
    var newAmount = Number(price.substring(1, price.length));
    if (newAmount) {
        var maxChange = Math.round(1.4 * checkedValue.value);
        if (newAmount <= maxChange) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(checkedValue.class)[1].innerHTML = newAmount;
        } else {
            alert('Too high!');
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VAfK2/2/).

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the recommendation.  That is much simpler than what I was using above.  So once user selects radio button, value appears in text box, but I allow user to edit the value as needed.  But I want to cap the increase to their edit to 40% of the original field value.  So they select radio button #1, displaying $700, they can now increase value up to $980, but any value above $980 results in app alert with message...  Thanks in advance if code exists for this.  Not sure if jquery is required here??

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense! i will try 'er out! Nah, plain javascript is doable fo sho

Comment: Try that! I updated the code so that you can only update each number up to 40% higher than their original value.